# How to convert solana block time to normal time?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, solana, solana-web3js

I'm using solana API and as a result of one function I get such response:

```
{
  blockTime: 1646251782,
  confirmationStatus: 'finalized',
  err: null,
  memo: null,
  signature: 'xyz',
  slot: 123192670
}
```

As you can see, there is `blockTime` field, and I want to extract value from it. When I was doing it with `moment`:

```
console.log(moment(1646251782).toISOString())
```

I got 1970 year, but it's incorrect, and I check this on solana explorer, and there was normal time. How can I get normal date or what do I do wrong?

Comment: hint: javascript stores date in milliseconds - it is currently 1,651,643,108,016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `unix` time in milliseconds, using moment you can extract time using this:

```
moment.unix(1650493606).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: These are seconds, not milliseconds.